# Pairwise hamming distance for binary data with missing values

Tags: rust

I just started learning Rust and my first project is a command line tool generating a pairwise distance matrix for binary data while ignoring missing values. The input files look like so:

```
001N0
011N0
10N10
```

with `N` denoting missing values that should be ignored. The example yields

```
0,1,1
1,0,2
1,2,0
```

After parsing the command line args with `clap` each sample (i.e. line in input file) is parsed into a struct `BitArrNA` holding 2 `bitvec`; one called `bits` for the data (with `N` as `0`) and one called `not_nas` specifying the positions of not-NA-values (`0` if `N`, else `1`). To get the hamming distance between two `BitArrNA` three bitwise operations are necessary: I chose `^` between the two `bits`, `&` between the two `not_nas` and `&` between the two results. All samples are compared with each other and the distances are stored in a triangular matrix (a vector of vectors) in the struct `TriMat` before being written as comma-separated symmetric matrix to the output file.

#### Errors

After some reading about error handling philosophies in Rust, I decided to go with two strategies:

- Errors caused by invalid input are handled with `unwrap_or_else` and `std::process::exit`
- Other errors indicate internal bugs in my code/logic and should throw a `panic` with `expect`

#### Questions

- What could have been done in a more idiomatic way?
- Are there any low-hanging fruits in terms of performance / efficiency / concurrency?
- Is the error-handling suitable?

#### Code

main.rs

```
use binary_hamming_dist::bitarr::BitArrNa;
use binary_hamming_dist::cli::parse_cmd_line;
use binary_hamming_dist::trimat::TriMat;
use indicatif::{ProgressBar, ProgressStyle};
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::fs;
use std::io;
use std::io::BufRead;

type Dist = u32;

fn main() {
    // get command line arguments
    let (infname, na_char, output, threads): (String, char, Option<String>, usize) =
        parse_cmd_line();

    // create thread pool
    rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder::new()
        .num_threads(threads)
        .build_global()
        .expect("Error initializing threadpool");

    // parse file into bitarr vec
    let mut bitarrs: Vec<BitArrNa> = Vec::new();
    let infile = fs::File::open(infname).unwrap_or_else(|err| {
        eprintln!("Error opening input file: {}", err);
        std::process::exit(1);
    });
    let infile = io::BufReader::new(infile);

    for (i, line) in infile.lines().enumerate() {
        if let Ok(line) = line {
            bitarrs.push(BitArrNa::from_string(&line, na_char).unwrap_or_else(|err| {
                eprintln!("Error generating bitarr at line {}: {}", i + 1, err);
                std::process::exit(1);
            }));
        } else {
            eprintln!("Error reading input file at line {}", i + 1);
            std::process::exit(1);
        }
    }

    // create Vec of Vecs for holding the distances (resembling a triangular matrix)
    let n = bitarrs.len();
    let mut dists: TriMat<Dist> = TriMat::new(n - 1);

    // setup progress bar
    let pb = ProgressBar::new(n as u64);
    pb.set_style(
        ProgressStyle::default_bar()
            .template("[{elapsed_precise}] [{bar:50.cyan/blue}] {pos}/{len} ({eta})")
            .progress_chars("#>-"),
    );

    // get the distances
    dists
        .mat
        .par_iter_mut()
        .zip(bitarrs[..n - 1].par_iter()) // skip last sample
        .enumerate()
        .for_each(|(i, (dists_i, bitarr_i))| {
            for bitarr_j in &bitarrs[i + 1..] {
                dists_i.push(bitarr_i.dist(bitarr_j));
            }
            pb.inc(1);
        });
    pb.finish_with_message("done");

    // write result to file
    if let Some(outfname) = output {
        let mut file = fs::File::create(&outfname).unwrap_or_else(|err| {
            eprintln!("Error opening output file: {}", err);
            std::process::exit(1);
        });
        dists.write_symmetric(&mut file);
        println!("Result written to {}", outfname);
    } else {
        dists.write_symmetric(&mut io::stdout());
    }
}
```

lib.rs -- only declaring modules for other lib files

```
pub mod bitarr;
pub mod cli;
pub mod trimat;
```

cli.rs -- holds function for command line parsing

```
pub fn parse_cmd_line() -> (String, char, Option<String>, usize) {
    let matches = clap::App::new("Binary Hamming Distance Calculator")
        .about(
            "Calculates the pairwise distance matrix of binary strings and \
             tolerates missing values. \n\
             The input file should hold one sample per line and look like: \n\n\
             001X0 \n\
             011X0 \t where 'X' denotes a missing value. This yields \n\
             10X10 \n\n\
             0,1,1 \n\
             1,0,2 \t as result.\n\
             1,2,0 \n",
        )
        .version(clap::crate_version!())
        .arg(
            clap::Arg::with_name("input")
                .help("input file")
                .takes_value(true)
                .short("i")
                .long("input")
                .required(true)
                .value_name("FILE")
                .display_order(1),
        )
        .arg(
            clap::Arg::with_name("NA-char")
                .help("the character [A-Za-z2-9] specifying missing values")
                .takes_value(true)
                .default_value("X")
                .possible_values(&[
                    "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P",
                    "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f",
                    "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v",
                    "w", "x", "y", "z", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
                ])
                .hide_possible_values(true)
                .short("n")
                .long("NA-value")
                .value_name("CHAR")
                .display_order(2),
        )
        .arg(
            clap::Arg::with_name("output")
                .help("output file; if missing, result is printed to STDOUT")
                .takes_value(true)
                .short("o")
                .long("output")
                .value_name("FILE")
                .display_order(3),
        )
        .arg(
            clap::Arg::with_name("threads")
                .help("number of threads; '0' will use all available CPUs")
                .takes_value(true)
                .short("t")
                .long("threads")
                .default_value("1")
                .value_name("NUM"),
        )
        .get_matches();

    // calling unwrap is safe here because `input` was `required` by clap
    // and `NA-char` has a default as well as allowed arguments.
    let infname = matches.value_of("input").unwrap().to_string();
    let na_char = matches.value_of("NA-char").unwrap().chars().next().unwrap();
    let output = match matches.value_of("output") {
        None => None,
        Some(fname) => Some(fname.to_string()),
    };
    let threads: usize = matches
        .value_of("threads")
        .unwrap()
        .parse()
        .unwrap_or_else(|err| {
            eprintln!(
                "Error parsing command line arguments: {}. \n\
                 Please provide a valid integer value for the threads argument",
                err
            );
            std::process::exit(1);
        });
    (infname, na_char, output, threads)
}
```

bitarr.rs -- holds `BitArrNA` struct

```
use bitvec::prelude as bv;
use itertools::izip;
use std::fmt;

pub struct BitArrNa {
    pub bits: bv::BitVec<bv::Local, usize>,
    pub not_nas: bv::BitVec<bv::Local, usize>,
}

impl BitArrNa {
    // create new `BitArrNa` with all-zero bits and all-one not_nas
    pub fn new(size: usize) -> BitArrNa {
        let bits = bv::bitvec![0; size];
        let not_nas = bv::bitvec![1; size];

        BitArrNa { bits, not_nas }
    }

    pub fn from_string(string: &str, na_char: char) -> Result<BitArrNa, String> {
        let mut bitarr = BitArrNa::new(string.len());
        for (i, c) in string.chars().enumerate() {
            if c == '0' {
                continue;
            } else if c == '1' {
                bitarr.bits.set(i, true);
            } else if c == na_char {
                bitarr.not_nas.set(i, false);
            } else {
                return Err(format!(
                    "Char at position {} was \'{}\'; expected \'0\', \'1\' or \'{}\'.",
                    i + 1,
                    c,
                    na_char
                ));
            }
        }

        Ok(bitarr)
    }

    pub fn dist<T>(&self, other: &BitArrNa) -> T
    where
        T: num_traits::Num + num_traits::cast::FromPrimitive,
    {
        let mut result: T = T::zero();

        for (bits, not_nas, other_bits, other_not_nas) in izip!(
            self.bits.as_slice(),
            self.not_nas.as_slice(),
            other.bits.as_slice(),
            other.not_nas.as_slice()
        ) {
            let res_bits = bits ^ other_bits;
            let res_not_nas = not_nas & other_not_nas;
            let incr = T::from_u32((res_bits & res_not_nas).count_ones())
                .expect("Error converting distance to requested type");
            result = result + incr;
        }

        result
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for BitArrNa {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "bits:\t\t{}\nnot_nas:\t{}", self.bits, self.not_nas)
    }
}
```

trimat.rs -- holds `TriMat` struct

```
use std::cmp;
use std::io;
use std::ops;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct TriMat<T> {
    pub mat: Vec<Vec<T>>,
}

impl<T> TriMat<T> {
    pub fn new(n: usize) -> TriMat<T> {
        let mut mat: Vec<Vec<T>> = Vec::with_capacity(n);
        for i in 0..n {
            mat.push(Vec::with_capacity(n - i));
        }
        TriMat { mat }
    }
}

impl<T> TriMat<T>
where
    T: num_traits::Zero + std::string::ToString + Copy,
{
    pub fn write_symmetric<Buffer: io::Write>(&self, buffer: &mut Buffer) {
        let n = self.mat.len();
        for i in 0..n + 1 {
            let mut line: Vec<T> = Vec::with_capacity(n);
            for j in 0..n + 1 {
                let dist: T;
                if i == j {
                    dist = T::zero();
                } else {
                    let smaller = cmp::min(i, j);
                    let larger = cmp::max(i, j);
                    dist = self[smaller][larger - smaller - 1];
                }
                line.push(dist);
            }
            let line: Vec<String> = line.into_iter().map(|i| i.to_string()).collect();
            writeln!(buffer, "{}", &line.join(","))
                .expect(&format!("Error writing result at i: {}", i));
        }
    }
}

impl<T> ops::Index<usize> for TriMat<T> {
    type Output = Vec<T>;

    fn index(&self, i: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.mat[i]
    }
}

impl<T> ops::IndexMut<usize> for TriMat<T> {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, i: usize) -> &mut Self::Output {
        &mut self.mat[i]
    }
}
```

cargo.toml

````
[package]
name = "binary_hamming_dist"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
bitvec = "0.17.4"
itertools = "0.9.0"
rayon = "1.3.0"
indicatif = "0.14.0"
clap = "~2.27.0"
num-traits = "0.2.11"
```
````